# HTTP2 protocol with playframewok

Tags: playframework, http2

How can I do a Basic HTTP2 server in PlayFramework 2.X?

Currenly HTTP2 protocol is implementable in production?

Comment: Play v2.6.x now supports HTTP/2 (however, still not production ready yet): https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Highlights26

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Things have changed since this was first answered and we've worked on implementing HTTP/2 in Akka HTTP since. Akka HTTP has become the default backend for Play in 2.6 so now it can be used.

Documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AkkaHttpServer#HTTP/2-support-(experimental)

Please note that as of writing this comment (early July 2017) support for HTTP/2 is still experimental, which means there's a few missing bits we know we need to implement (and are going to in the coming weeks; In the meantime, feedback from the community trying it out in the real world would be very valuable,
 thanks!)

Comment: Hi @Konrad, would you have an estimation when does the production-ready (i.e., non-experimental) HTTP2 support will be available?

Answer (score 2):

No, Play 2 does not yet support HTTP/2.
Play uses akka, which does not have HTTP/2 support yet. See this bug: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/16862

Also read this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework-dev/N4GaWYZ19-A

Comment: Still not supported as of today, but it seems to be on the way : 
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5817

Comment: That is not correct, Play uses Netty. I'm not sure how this is an accepted answer. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration#Server-configuration-options

Comment: It's a good answer -- the plan is to provide HTTP/2 through the akka-http engine, and it's still in progress.

Comment: Note that Akka's HTTP/2 support in Play has landed in 2.6 as an experimental feature, try it here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AkkaHttpServer#HTTP/2-support-(experimental)